# MLT Move video upper?

Tags: mlt

Had to make something like this, but i can't find way how to move video which is at middle a bit upper...

[image]

```
melt in.mp4 
-filter watermark:"title.jpg" composite.progressive=1 producer.align=centre composite.valign=top composite.halign=c
-filter watermark:"bottom.jpg" composite.progressive=1 producer.align=centre composite.valign=bottom composite.halign=c
-filter crop left=128 right=128 
-profile square_profile.txt -consumer avformat:"out.mp4" vcodec=libx264 vb=3500k ab=128k
```

So how to move centered video upper? Can't find such filter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "affine" filter can be used to change the size and position of the video frame:
https://mltframework.org/plugins/FilterAffine/

The affine filter is really just a convenience wrapper that combines a black producer (for the background) and an affine transition:
https://mltframework.org/plugins/TransitionAffine/

You can modify the affine transition properties by setting "transition.*" properties on the affine filter. For example, to set the size and position of the frame, use "transition.geometry".

```
melt in.mp4 -filter affine transition.geometry="-40/40:700x500" transition.distort=0 transition.fill=0 \
    -filter watermark:"bottom.jpg" composite.progressive=1 producer.align=centre composite.valign=bottom composite.halign=c \
    -filter watermark:"bottom.jpg" composite.progressive=1 producer.align=centre composite.valign=bottom composite.halign=c \
    -profile square_profile.txt -consumer avformat:"out.mp4" vcodec=libx264 vb=3500k ab=128k
```

The geometry specification is: "X/Y:WxH". So set those according to your needs. The X and Y values can be negative in order to crop off parts that you don't want to display.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... profile - 640x640 (For instagram) As i see you resized address title (title.jpg), and i need to move in.mp4 a bit upper. so in.mp4 -transition composite composite.geometry="-20/0:100%x100%" - should that work?

Comment: Sorry. I understand your question better now. See my updated answer. You will need to experiment with the geometry value to get your desired results.